Can I make an endpoint that returns both thymeleaf template and JSON object?
I was wondering if I could combine my html template String and a json inside an endpoint, so I can have an endpoint that returns the web template for my app and I can also visualize in Postman the json object. I was trying to do it with @ModelAndView Annotation, but I am not able to get the Json format in Postman. Could you help me? Is there a way to do this, or will I have to split the endpoint in two?
 @GetMapping("/pacientes")
    @ResponseBody
    public ModelAndView listaPacientes() {
        List<PacienteDTO> pacienteDTOList = pacienteService.obtenerPacientes();
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("pacientes");
        modelAndView.addObject("pacientes", pacienteDTOList);
        return modelAndView;
    }

Postman response
Im trying to combine HTML template + json objets in one endpoint

No. You need 2 different endpoints (selected on the requested content type) one returning an object to be serialized into JSON/XML/... the other returning the view.
